Deriving Beltrami identity when there are multiple dependent functions
I'm trying to understand this solution to the brachistochrone problem inside a uniform sphere. Going from equation (19) to (20) and (21), the integrand of the functional we're trying to minimize is of the form $f(x,x',y,y')$, where $x$ and $y$ are both functions of time $t$. It says to use Beltrami identities to get that $f - x'\frac{\partial f}{\partial x'}$ and $f - y'\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'}$ are each constant (the same method is also used here and here, where it's called the "second form" of Euler's equation). I'm getting confused trying to show that these identities hold.
What I did was try to parallel the derivation for the case where there's only one dependent function like $f(x,x')$, which I know how to do. In that case, what we do is write
$$
\frac{df}{dt} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} x' + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x'} x'' + \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}.
$$
We say $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} = 0$ since there's no explicit time dependence, and by the Euler-Lagrange equation we get
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{df}{dt} &= \frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x'}\right) x' + \frac{\partial f} {\partial x'} x'' \\ &= \frac{d}{dt} \left(x' \frac{\partial f}{\partial x'}\right),
\end{align}
$$
so $\frac{d}{dt} (f - x' \frac{\partial f}{\partial x'}) = 0$. Now if I try this with $f(x,x',y,y')$, since $f$ depends on both $x$ and $y$ I would have to write
$$
\frac{df}{dt} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} x' + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x'} x'' + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} y' + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y'} y'' +\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}.
$$
Doing the same thing as above,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{df}{dt} &= \frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x'}\right) x' + \frac{\partial f} {\partial x'} x'' + \frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'}\right) y' + \frac{\partial f} {\partial y'} y'' \\ 
&= \frac{d}{dt} \left(x' \frac{\partial f}{\partial x'}\right) + \frac{d}{dt} \left(y' \frac{\partial f}{\partial y'}\right).
\end{align}
$$
But then I end up getting a single identity saying $f - x'\frac{\partial f}{\partial x'} - y'\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'}$ is constant, with both $x'$ and $y'$ being there together. In my understanding this derivation is pretty much analogous to the Hamitonian $H = \sum \dot{q}_i \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}_i} - L$ being constant when the Lagrangian doesn't explicitly depend on time, an identity which features all the $\dot{q}_i$ at once. The identities I need however require $f - x'\frac{\partial f}{\partial x'}$ and $f - y'\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'}$ being constant separately. How would I get to those? Am I allowed to just ignore $y$ and $y'$ and do the same thing as the case with just $f(x,x')$? That doesn't feel correct, or at least I don't see the justification since taking the total derivative of $f$ should involve everything it depends on. What am I missing here?

No, equations (20), and (21) are wrong. It doesn’t make sense (barring silly trivial cases) to obtain two conservation laws (namely (20) and (21)) from a single cyclic quantity (namely explicit $t$-independence). The time-independence implies the single conservation law for the energy $-E=f-\dot{x}\frac{\partial f}{\partial\dot{x}}-\dot{y}\frac{\partial f}{\partial \dot{y}}$. But actually in this specific case, it turns out the RHS vanishes identically, so this isn’t a useful conservation law.
But, there is another conserved quantity: for simplicity, set $g=1$ and rescale coordinates to set $R=1$. Then, we have
\begin{align}
f=\sqrt{\frac{\dot{r}^2+r^2\dot{\theta}^2}{1-r^2}},
\end{align}
and so observing that it doesn’t depend on $\theta$, it follows that the corresponding momentum
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial \dot{\theta}}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\frac{\dot{r}^2+r^2\dot{\theta}^2}{1-r^2}}}\cdot\frac{2r^2\dot{\theta}}{1-r^2}=\frac{r^2\dot{\theta}}{\sqrt{\dot{r}^2+r^2\dot{\theta}^2}\sqrt{1-r^2}}=\frac{x\dot{y}-y\dot{x}}{\sqrt{\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2}\sqrt{1-(x^2+y^2)}},
\end{align}
is conserved along the solutions of the equations of motion. If you call this $\lambda$, then you can verify that the hypocycloid does indeed make this constant. So, the hypocycloid is consistent with this observation (but keep in mind this reasoning still doesn’t imply that the solutions of the Euler-Lagrange equations are hypocycloids).
For this, I think it really is best to reduce to the case of one independent variable, so you rewrite it as $f(r,r’)=\sqrt{\frac{(r’)^2+r^2}{1-r^2}}$, where $r’=\frac{dr}{d\theta}$. Because now, the resulting equation is a single ODE for $r(\theta)$, rather than a coupled system of ODEs for $(x(t),y(t))$. This keeps in line with the general philosophy of having as many conservation laws as possible (so in 1D, having one non-trivial conservation law will essentially allow you to solve the ODE ‘in closed form’ (up to the difficulty of actually carrying out the integration)). And now, by using that this $f$ doesn’t depend on the parameter $\theta$, we have ‘energy conservation’: $f-r’\frac{\partial f}{\partial r’}$ is constant. Now, integrating this yields a hypocycloid, and the details are indeed carried out in the second reference of our first link (Donald Smith, Variational Methods in Optimization, section 4.2).

Showing that Equations (20), (21) really are wrong.
First of all, equations (20), (21) have typos on the right hand sides (a few minus signs should be plus). As I mentioned above, a direct calculation reveals that $f-\dot{x}\frac{\partial f}{\partial\dot{x}}-\dot{y}\frac{\partial f}{\partial \dot{y}} =0$ identically. So,
\begin{align}
f-\dot{x}\frac{\partial f}{\partial\dot{x}}&=\dot{y}\frac{\partial f}{\partial \dot{y}}= \sqrt{\frac{R}{g}}\sqrt{\frac{\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2}{R^2-(x^2+y^2)}}\cdot \frac{\dot{y}^2}{\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2}\tag{$1$}
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
f-\dot{y}\frac{\partial f}{\partial\dot{y}}&=\dot{x}\frac{\partial f}{\partial \dot{x}}=\sqrt{\frac{R}{g}}\sqrt{\frac{\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2}{R^2-(x^2+y^2)}}\cdot \frac{\dot{x}^2}{\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2}.\tag{$2$}
\end{align}
Equations (1),(2) here are the corrected versions of (20),(21) in the link. The link claims that each of these expressions is constant along solutions of the equations of motion (namely the hypocycloid). So, let’s actually check if this is true. I shall plug in the hypocycloids (see equations (24),(25))
\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
x(t)&=(R-b)\cos t+b\cos\left(\frac{R-b}{b}t\right)\\
y(t)&=(R-b)\sin t-b\sin\left(\frac{R-b}{b}t\right)
\end{cases}
\end{align}
into the right sides of equations (1) and (2) and check whether they really are constant. Actually to falsify the statements, I only need to check one of them is not constant (though the other one is almost similar); for the sake of concreteness, I’ll plug them into (1).
A direct calculation reveals that $\sqrt{\frac{\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2}{R^2-(x^2+y^2)}}=\sqrt{\frac{R-b}{b}}$ is constant, so we simply have to check whether or not $\frac{\dot{y}^2}{\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2}$ is constant; a direct calculation gives
\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
\dot{y}&=(R-b)\cos t-(R-b)\cos\left(\frac{R-b}{b}t\right)\\
\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2&=2(R-b)^2\left[1-\cos\left(\frac{R}{b}t\right)\right],
\end{cases}
\end{align}
where for the second equation we had to use the cosine addition formula a few times. For convenience, let us write $\xi:=\frac{R}{b}$, so that $\frac{R-b}{b}=\xi-1$. Then,
\begin{align}
\frac{\dot{y}^2}{\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2}&=\frac{[\cos t- \cos((\xi-1)t)]^2}{2(1-\cos(\xi t))}\\
&=\frac{\left[\cos(t)(1-\cos(\xi t))-\sin(t)\sin(\xi t)\right]^2}{2(1-\cos(\xi t))}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left[\cos^2(t)(1-\cos(\xi t))-2\sin t\cos t\sin(\xi t)+\frac{\sin^2(t)\sin^2(\xi t)}{1-\cos(\xi t)}\right]\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left[\cos^2(t)(1-\cos(\xi t))-2\sin t\cos t\sin(\xi t)+\sin^2(t)(1+\cos(\xi t))\right]\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left[(\cos^2t+\sin^2t)-\cos(\xi t)(\cos^2t-\sin^2t)-\sin(\xi t)(2\sin t\cos t)\right]\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left[1-\cos(\xi t)\cos(2t)-\sin(\xi t)\sin(2t)\right]\\
&=\frac{1-\cos((\xi-2)t)}{2},
\end{align}
where I used a bunch of trig identities ($\sin^2+\cos^2=1$, the double angle formulae, and the addition formula for cosine). Notice that this is clearly not a constant function of $t$ (unless $\xi=\frac{R}{b}=2$ of course, but this is an exceptional case). Therefore, we have shown that the RHS of equation (1) is not constant in time, thus proving that the link’s claim in equation (20) is wrong. Similarly for equation (21).
